# How to stop Backgroundworker and close the form?

Tags: .net, winforms, c#-4.0, controls, backgroundworker

I want to completely stop the BackgroundWorker DoWork() Process while running for closing the form.

I have applied following code but in  "this.Invoke" it throws error : "Invoke or BeginInvoke cannot be called on a control until the window handle has been created." while form close.

```
   private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            var dt_Images = db.Rings.Select(I => new { I.PaidRs, I.TypeID, I.RingID, I.CodeNo, Image = Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(I.Image.ToArray())) }).OrderByDescending(r => r.TypeID);
            foreach (var dr in dt_Images.ThenByDescending(r => r.RingID).ToList())
            {
                BTN = new Button();
                BTN.TextImageRelation = TextImageRelation.TextAboveImage;
                BTN.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.BottomCenter;
                BTN.AutoSize = true;
                BTN.Name = dr.RingID.ToString();
                BTN.Image = dr.Image;
                BTN.Text = dr.CodeNo.ToString() + "    " + dr.TypeID.ToString();
                this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { if (backgroundWorker1 != null) flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(BTN); else return; }));
                BTN.Click += new EventHandler(this.pic_Click);
                this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { if (backgroundWorker1 == null) txt_pcs.Text = flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Count.ToString(); else return;}));
            }
        }

  private void Form_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyData == Keys.Escape)
            {
                backgroundWorker1.CancelAsync(); //backgroundworker doesnt stop here
                backgroundWorker1 = null;   //it still invokes the delegate
                this.Dispose();  
            }
        }
```

How to solved this error?

please help me.

Answer (score 2):

You have to watch for the cancel request inside your worker. Like

```
private void DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) 
{ 
 var worker = sender as BackgroundWorker; 

 while (!worker.CancellationPending) 
 { 
   … 
 } 

 if (worker.CancellationPending) 
 { 
  e.Cancel = true; 
 } 
}
```

Comment: That's still not enough. If you don't check if worker has really stopped before disposing, there is a race condition which will cause the exception every once in a while.

Comment: I have applied above code but getting same problem.@Israel Lot

Answer (score 1):

The actual problem is that there is no way to safely check if form is being closed before calling `Invoke` in a background thread.

To remedy this, what you can do is to postpone closing a bit, until the background thread has the chance to exit the main loop.

First, declare two flags and a lock object:

```
private volatile bool _closeRequest = false;
private volatile bool _workerStopped = false;
private readonly object _lock = new object();
```

Then, when you want to close the form, simply call `Close`:

```
private void Form_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyData == Keys.Escape)
    {
        Close();
    }
}
```

Inside `FormClosing`, check if worker has already stopped. This part must be inside a monitor, to prevent a race-condition when background thread is just being finished (i.e. to ensure that `_workerStopped` and `_closeRequest` are updated atomically):

```
protected override void OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    lock (_lock)
    {
        // if not stopped
        if (!_workerStopped)
        {
            // delay closing
            e.Cancel = true;

            // notify worker
            _closeRequest = true;
        }
    }
    base.OnFormClosing(e);
}
```

Finally, in your background thread, actually close the form if needed:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        foreach (var dr in GetImages())
        {
            if (_closeRequest)
                break;

            // ... do stuff
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        lock (_lock)
        {
            // notify we stopped
            _workerStopped = true;

            // if closing was postponed, close now
            if (_closeRequest)
                BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(Close));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why choose AutoResetEvent over backgroundWorker1.CancelAsync()? Is there a benefit? Just curious.

Comment: @PoweRoy: you are right, the first part could be also done by calling `CancelAsync` and polling `BackgorundWorker.CancellationPending` inside the worker method. This is just slightly more general, and will work when a simple background thread is used as a worker.

Comment: using this method but at this process "_workerStopped.WaitOne();" cursor going on wait. @Groo

Comment: @Tulsi: ok, that's right, I didn't give it enough thought, it's slightly more complicated. I will update my answer in a moment.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple program which, I think, will give you an idea of how take care of a closing of a form while a `BackgroundWorker` is running:

```
int i = 0;//This is to show progress.
bool cancel;//This is to notify RunWorkerCompleted to Close() the Form if needed.

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    FormClosing += Form1_FormClosing;

    backgroundWorker1.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
    backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted += backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted;
    backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
}

void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    //Since this is executed on the main thread - it is not (as far as I know) going to "race" against the FormClosing.
    if (cancel) Close();
    else Text = "Done";
}

void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    if (backgroundWorker1.IsBusy)
    {
        cancel = true;
        backgroundWorker1.CancelAsync();
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    backgroundWorker1.CancelAsync();
}

//This is executed on a separate thread:
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    while (!backgroundWorker1.CancellationPending)
    {
        Invoke((Action)(() => Text = (i++).ToString()));
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
    e.Cancel = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your DoWork method you have to check against `backgroundWorker1.CancellationPending` before starting to process the next image.

You have to waiting until the last image is processed before allowing the user to close the form.

For a comlete example of how to use `CancellationPending` and `Cancel` properties see [this MSDN example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx)

Comment: i have also used MSDN example but same problem occurs.@Philip Fourie